# FCM - Is messageId different on backend and frontend?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a backend application which send push notifications to FCM. FCM responds with messageId to that request. And in my mobile application, there is a messageId as well when a notification is received. Are those two messageIds the same?

Also I can query BigQuery to get message's status by enabling [BigQuery Data Export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#bigquery-data-export). If those two messageIds are not the same, which messageId should I use to query the table?

Answer (score 0):

When talking about the relationship of **back-end and front-end**, it always sums up as **tandem**. For whatever is existing in the user's side, it also exists in the server side. **Firebase generates messageID on back-end** when having an **API call**, then it will be **visible on the front-end**. Therefore, `messageID is the same`. Also, the value of the messageID can be non-unique.